# cross-application server Web service annotations

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish, wildfly

This may seem like an absurd question and to some maybe ignorant, but I'm new to J2EE and just picking on. So kindly help me understand.
I came across a tutorial in web service creation with Glassfish 4. I successfully created a very simple WS using the `@WebService` annotation and the like (Glassfish generated the WSDL and tester based on the annotations).

I wanted to try using WildFly (previously JBoss AS). So I deployed the same web app in Wildfly. But the server console threw an error saying that `@WebService` annotation cannot have some of the properties I used (like `serviceName`, `bindingName` etc).

Can someone please explain why a J2EE annotation wont work on a full fledged, up-to-date application server when it worked on another?

Comment: Appserver (can) have different implementations of the same standard.

Comment: Remember J2EE is a specification just like SQL and vendors compete on these specifications with various implementations. Some MySQL will not work on Oracle the same with WildFly and GlassFish.

Comment: That analogy doesn't apply here @Namphibian; The [JAX-WS Specification(JSR-181)](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224) dictates specifically what attributes the `@WebService` annotation must support, specifically for cross-platform compatibility at a very basic level. If for some reason JBoss doesn't support those attributes (which I seriously doubt), then WildFly is not JSR-181-compliant. OP needs to post the exact stacktrace here; this is most likely a dependency-management issue

Comment: @kolossus note that the `@WebService` annotation is supported. The op clearly states that some of the optional extras seems to cause the problem. I am pretty sure JBoss is compliant however some of these tutorials are geared towards a specific implementation rather than the standard and this normally leads to confusion. I fully agree with you however.

Comment: J2EE is obsolete, it's Java EE.

Comment: @hwellmann yeah old habits die hard. Java EE it  is. Man I am getting old I remember when Java was a baby. Hell I remeber loading programs from cassettes and 10MB hard drives.

Comment: You had a hard drive? I only had two floppy drives at university...

Answer (score 0):

`bindingName` is not a legal element of the [`javax.jws.WebService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jws/WebService.html) annotation.